# Query Performance greater than primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Reporting table where i store description

```
tableA

sno   | Project |name     | description      | mins |
1     | prjA    |nameA    |ABC -10% task done|  30  |
...
3000  | prjA    |nameB    |ABC -70% task done|  70  |
```

i want to query the description field and save in another table

```
tableB

id | valueStr | total_mins  | last_sno
1  |  ABC     | 100         | 3000
```

if there is no entry in second table , i create a entry with default values

if there is and entry in second table , i update 2nd table , with the total_mins and increment the last_sno to that value say 3300 , so that the next time i query this table i get values from second table and based on the last_sno

Query

```
SELCT last_sno FROM tableB where valueStr ='ABC'

the first 3 characters in the description field

SELECT max(sno), sum(mins) FROM tableA
 where sno > last_sno and description like 'ABC%'
```

Since the first table has million of rows so, 
i search the first table with sno > last_sno , so that should help performance right ?

but the explain shows that it scans the same no of rows , when i query the first table from the first sno

Answer (score 1):

The use of the index may not help you, because MySQL still has to scan the index from the `last_sno` to the end of the data.  You would be better off with an index on `TableA(description)`, because such an index can be used for `description like 'ABC%'`.

In fact, this might be a case where the index can hurt you.  Instead of sequentially reading the pages in the table, the index reads them randomly -- which is less efficient.

EDIT:  (too long for comment)

Try running the query with an `ignore index` hint to see if you can run the query without it.  It is possible that the index is actually making things worse.

However, the "real" solution is to store the prefix you are interested in as a separate column.  You can then add an index on this column and the query should work efficiently using basic SQL.  You won't have to spend your time trying to optimize a simple process, because the data will be stored correctly for it.

Comment: is there any other way apart from adding index to tableA, as its a Important table and i don't want to change it.

Comment: in the where clause, the sno > last_sno , if it fails will take less time than comparing the text right?

Comment: @NaveenKumar . .  Because `sno` is the primary key, then scanning the primary key index should go faster with the comparison.  If it were just a regular column, then that is not necessarily the case, because the pages will not be read sequentially.